# Copy UIView using archiver - memory release?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am copying a UIView so that when I remove sub views from the copy (B) it doesn't affect the original (A). I am using archivedDataWithRootObject and unarchiveObjectWithData like so:

```
NSData *viewData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:viewA];
UIView *viewB = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:viewData];
```

However I don't know whether doing this means every time I archive a view it is stored on the iPone forever or whether it is released at some point. I looked at the class reference but didn't find an answer.

I am using XCode 6, IOS 7.1 and Objective C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executive summary: what you're doing looks fine and doesn't appear to leak memory, assuming you don't save the `NSData` somewhere and you treat the view copy like a normal view.

More details: Your first line creates an `NSData`.  When all strong references to this `NSData` are released, the system will deallocate it and reclaim its memory.  If `viewB` is a local variable, and you don't store a pointer to the `NSData` anywhere else, then it will be released before the system delivers the next event (touch, alarm, whatever), when the run loop drains the autorelease pool.

Your second line creates a `UIView`.  When all strong references to this `UIView` are released, the system will deallocate it and reclaim its memory.  Presumably you are adding the view as a subview of another view; that superview will retain the subview.  Later, eventually, if you remove the subview from the superview, or when the superview is deallocated, and you drop any other references you have to the view, it will be released before the system delivers another event, when the run loop drains the autorelease pool.

Using an archiver to create an `NSData` doesn't create anything “permanent” - it doesn't create any files in the filesystem.  If you don't write the `NSData` to a file, then certainly the system will reclaim its memory, and all other memory private to your process, when your process exits (due to a reboot, crash, or low memory warning while some other app is in the foreground).